# In batch insert, how to continue inserting other rows when an error occurred in one row

Tags: hibernate, batch-processing

In my code I am doing a batch insert. For an example think that I have five rows to insert, and one of those fails when inserting. Then hibernate prevent inserting all the rows.

In my case I want to insert other four records which contains no errors. Is this possible in Hibernate?

Following is a simplified version of my code.

```
void save() {
  Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction transaction = session1.beginTransaction();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    BatchSizeConf r = new BatchSizeConf();//This is my entity
    r.setId(i);
    r.setDispatchType("Disp");
    r.setBatchSize(500);
    Serializable z = session1.save(r);
    System.out.println(z);//prints ids
  }

  session1.flush();
  session1.clear();
  session1.getTransaction().commit();
  session1.close();
}
```

**EDIT**:

---

According to following answers below I changed my code and solved my main problem. Now my code is like this.

```
void save() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session1.beginTransaction();

    BatchSizeConf r = new BatchSizeConf();//This is my entity
    r.setId(i);
    r.setDispatchType("Disp");
    r.setBatchSize(500);

    try {
      session1.save(r);
      transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
      System.out.println("Failed: " + i);
    }

    session1.flush();
    session1.clear();
    session1.close();
  }
}
```

I Now I have another two questions.

1. Is it ok to create multiple session objects like above? (I have more than 100000 records.)
2. Do I need to call `flush()`, `clear()` and `close()` methods as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
...
for (BatchSizeConf  b: BatchSizeConfList) {
    ...
    tx.commit();
}
```

Refer [Avaoid transaction exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909827/why-org-hibernate-transactionexception-in-hibernate-and-avoid)

Comment: Thanks @The Suresh Atta. I modified my code and please take a look at my modified question.

Comment: No when transaction commits  no need to call session flush .

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, transaction will be marked as rollback by any exception.

Why don't chipped rows into chunks and set single transaction per each chunk?

Take a look this docs [transactions-demarcation-exceptions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions)

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException, immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close() and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

Comment: Thanks @dgregory. I modified my code and please take a look at my modified question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. We can do.. See this code.

```
public List<RecordErrorStatus> persistBatch(ArrayList<?> domainRecords) {

        List<RecordErrorStatus> fedRecordErrorStatusList = new ArrayList<RecordErrorStatus>();
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        long rowCount = 0;
        boolean insertionFailed=false;
        for (Object object : domainRecords) {
            rowCount++;
            try {
                System.out.println("Inserting Record:"+rowCount+object);
                session.persist(object); // Persist the given transient instance
                if (! this.rollBackOnFail) {
                    tx.commit();
                    tx = session.beginTransaction();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                RecordErrorStatus feedRecordStatus = new RecordErrorStatus();
                feedRecordStatus.setRowNumber(String.valueOf(rowCount));
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                String exceptionAsString = sw.toString();
                feedRecordStatus.setErrorDescription(exceptionAsString);
                fedRecordErrorStatusList.add(feedRecordStatus);
                insertionFailed =true;
                tx.rollback(); //Rollback the current record..
                session.clear();//Clear the seesion.. If not, throws Nested Transaction not allowd...
                tx = session.beginTransaction();//Start again..
            } 
        }
        if (this.rollBackOnFail && insertionFailed && ! tx.wasRolledBack()) {
            tx.rollback();
            System.out.println("Rollback");
        } 
        return fedRecordErrorStatusList;
    }
```