# Hibernate and/or JDBC batch insert/update exception handling

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, transactions

Suppose I am inserting 100 rows in a batch operation in Hibernate, similar to:

```
beginTx with flush mode manual;

insert 100 rows;
do 100 times {
    insert row
    commit;
}
flush;
clear;
```

Ideally, this should translate into a batch operation (since batch-size param, keys set by Hibernate, etc).
But suppose one of the inserts in the batch fail on FK constraint, or whatever.
Individual rows were committed, but the problem (constraint violation) only during flush.

Is this scenario possible? (I was 100% sure this is what happens here until now)
If so, should I worry about it, or does JDBC or Hibernate take care of business?
What's the best approach to handle this?

Thanks.

-- Edit: Here's the exception

```
ERROR Caught exception while trying to flush: 
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:132)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:217)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:472)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
...

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '218947-449145434175721472' for key 'Unique XXX AAA and BBB'
    ...   

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '218947-449145434175721472' for key 'Unique XXX AAA and BBB'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems possible duplicate of this one [In batch insert, how to continue inserting other rows when an error occurred in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170049/in-batch-insert-how-to-continue-inserting-other-rows-when-an-error-occurred-in)

and there you can also see the answer.

Comment: You are right in the sense that my question was far from clear. I wrote it late at night :-). Updated the question - please take a look. And thanks for spending the time.

Comment: Bit confused now, you opened a trx with manual flush mode and doing flush after the commit. Why do you want to do the flush mode manual?

Comment: if possible paste the complete code instead of pseudo, which may give full picture

Comment: I would, but it's complex and would confuse. I actually have a listener that receives messages at an unknown rate, and does the inserts and the commits. I have another thread that takes that data, periodically, and flushes it / clears it. Not your typical bulk. But the pseudo is a good representation (may not be correct - I'm open to suggestions). The flush is manual - because I want the actual inserts to happen in bulk. Otherwise performance is a problem.